# shopify and instafeed.js compatibility issues

Tags: javascript, api, shopify

I am trying to use shopify and instafeed.js together but I am getting no data returned on the page just some broken image icons. I have read about solutions here: [Instagram feed not returning any data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707055/instagram-feed-not-returning-any-data) and still cant figure out why. you can find my page here: http://supaslydes.com/ and at the very bottom you will see broken image links. This same code works on my local machine, but when I integrate it into shopify liquid file it breaks. Any known issues or solutions would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template option from instafeed is not compatible out of the box, remove it, save it, and re add it and it will work.